# How to reaim references c++

Tags: c++, reference, alias

Is there any way to initialise a reference to an object, and then reaim it at another object without resulting in a copy? What I mean is this:

```
    std::vector < int >& vec1 = someVector;
    std::vector < int >& vec2 = someOtherVector:
    if ( someCondition )
    {
        vec2 = someVector;//copying occurs here
        vec1 = someOtherVector;
    }
```

Instead, what I want is for `vec2` to be the reference to `someOtherVector` and `vec1` to be the reference to `someVector` if `someCondition` is satisfied, instead of them becoming copies. Unfortunately, something along the lines of:

```
     if ( someCondition )
     {
         std::vector < int >& vec1 = someVector;
         std::vector < int >& vec2 = someOtherVector;
     }
     else
     {
         std::vector < int >& vec1 = someOtherVector;
         std::vector < int >& vec2 = someVector;         
     }
```

would involve duplicating a lot of code in my program due to the scope of the references being limited to the `if` and `else` bodies, so is there some way around this problem? I was unsuccessful in finding a solution in my textbook or online.

Comment: You could use `std::swap` to do a similar thing.

Comment: Remark that what you see is not aliasing, but copying. At the declaration of a reference, the assignment (in fact initialization) makes the alias.  Afterwards, the assignment copies the source to whatever the reference is aliasing.  So vec1 and vec2 are identical when someCondition is true, but changing one of them will not be reflected in the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

References can't be reseated after initialisation; as you say, they are aliases for a specific object.

If the condition is known at initialisation time, then you can make the initialiser conditional:

```
std::vector<int>& vec1 = someCondition ? someVector : someOtherVector;
```

Otherwise, use pointers instead, or refactor the code using the references into another function as described in [Jerry Coffin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23611539/204847).

Answer (score 3):

Not with references. If you need that sort of behavior, you'd have to use `std::vector<int>*` instead of &.

```
std::vector < int >* vec1 = &someVector;
std::vector < int >* vec2 = &someOtherVector:
if ( someCondition )
{
    // could use std::swap to achieve this too
    vec2 = &someVector;//aliasing occurs here
    vec1 = &someOtherVector;
}
```

Comment: Ok, but Mike Seymour's first suggestion is a better one if the condition is indeed known at assignment time.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you'd be better off moving most of your code into a function, and have the condition in the calling code:

```
void f(std::vector<int> &, std::vector<int> &);

if (someCondition)
    f(somevector, someOtherVector);
else
    f(someOtherVector, somevector);
```

Then the rest of your code that uses the vectors would be inside of `f`.

Comment: Yes, I was actually thinking of putting it all in another function, but my orignal function is going to get called a lot, so I wasn't so sure about the cost of calling another function.

Comment: @user1922001: If the function is small enough that the overhead of the call becomes significant, chances are pretty good that the compiler can/will generate code for it inline. I normally ignore the cost of function calls until or unless a profiler tells me I really *can't* ignore it (which almost never happens).